# redraw vim window, is this a bug or feature?

Tags: vim, resize

I am using the vim editor (main buffer only).
If I edit a file and drag the window edge to change its horizontal size, 
the buffer will be redrawn when I type any key.
However, sometimes that is not the case  :-(

The redraw is dependent on the time between the window resize and
the key press.  If the time is less than 2 seconds (can vary a bit),
then the buffer will be redrawn.  If the time is more than 2 seconds
the window will not be redrawn.  At that point, if you do another
window resize and immediately type a key, then the buffer will be redrawn
as expected.  In other words, you need to watch the window carefully
to make sure the buffer has been redrawn properly.

Is this a bug or feature?

I wish there was no time threshold.
That is, the buffer would be redrawn at any time.
I tried to write an autocommand:

```
autocmd VimResized * ctrl-W
```

But it did not help.

Or maybe it is possible to have the buffer redrawn immediately
when the window is resized?  That is how gvim works  :-)

Thanks for any comments.

The following added on **7-24-16**
Let me explain the details of this bug/feature.

In order to verify this:

1. start vim
2. go to insert mode
3. hold down the letter <kbd>j</kbd> until you have 80 <kbd>j</kbd>s. Escape out of insert mode.
4. grab the right side of the vim window and move it to left 5 characters
5. wait 5 seconds
6. press the space bar
7. note whether the buffer was redrawn in step 6. That is, were the <kbd>j</kbd>s redrawn to fit the new window size?
8. go to step 4 and repeat 10 times.

You will observe that about 20% of the time the buffer was redrawn.
80% of the time the buffer was not redrawn  :-(
If you repeat with no delay in step 5, the buffer will be redrawn always.

The following autocmd did not help:

```
autocmd VimResized * ctrl-W
```

In order to create this autocmd, the keystrokes are:

```
autocmd VimResized * ctrl-V ctrl-W
```

thanks for comments

Comment: I am not sure whether `VimResized` exists. If it exists, you have to change your command. Use `<C-W>` instead of (C-W). Try this

Comment: SibiCoder,  Yes, I should have written <C-W>, not (C-W).  When I typed <C-W>, it was removed in the OP?  I have changed it to ctrl-W.

Comment: Didn't that command work? Then, instead `<C-W>`, insert `^w`. Press Ctrl and v and then W to insert `^w`

Comment: @SibiCoder  7-24-16 I have added details to the OP.  Have you tried to duplicate this?   I wish it worked the same as gvim.  If not, it should be consistent.

Comment: @SibiCoder,  OK I see the problem.  When I run vim from the cygwin terminal the buffer is redrawn automatically.  But if I run vim associated with a *.vim file, I  have a problem.  I see that cygwin Terminal is running xterm.  Now I need to find out if I can run xterm when running vim associated with a *.vim file.  I would mark this solved, but cannot see how to do it.